# Full width img in styled body tag

Tags: html, css, image, width

Hi i have a header image which I want to be 100% width, however my body tag is already styled with width, is there a way to override it? I tried putting the `img` `div` before the body tag in the HTML but that doesnt work, neither does using `!important` on the width of the `img` `div`

CSS: 
Header:

```
.header-img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 40%;
    background-image: url('/v2/img/header.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    position: relative;
}
```

body:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    font-family: 'Finger Paint', sans-serif;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header><div class='header-img'>title</div></header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your working upside down.
body is the wrapping element of the page, this is why it should have the maximum width/height.
you can try to play with the "position" css attr on the header element but thats just bad practice.

you need to create something like:

```
<body>
<header style="width:100%;">title</header>
<content style="width:60%">wrapper for all content</content>
```